# Modify SELECT from within WHERE

Tags: sql, avaya

**Background:**

I'm writing a report in Avaya CMS Supervisor. Now, if you don't know what that is, it doesn't really matter, since the question's about SQL. But if you *do* know about it, then it would most certainly help.

In this program, you can create reports which pull data out of a database (which is then shown to a user). Thing is; to create these reports, you have to use a (ridiculous) form of visual point-and-click-select-items sort of query builder. What you can do, though, is define every item to select (in the `SELECT`-clause) and every item in the `WHERE`-clause.

Now, my problem is that the only way to access user-input is within the `WHERE`.

**Question:**

Is it possible, through any hacks or whatever, to modify, from the `WHERE`, what values are shown in the `SELECT`?

If simple SQL-queries had (variable) variables, this would be more-or-less valid:

```
SELECT drv-tbl.$A
FROM drv-tbl
WHERE
    $b = (SELECT value AS $A FROM table) AS drv-tbl
```

Comment: You can use CASE in the select part, that might help. It will not change the column name, but you can have it return different values depending on conditions.

Comment: Well, as I wrote, the problem is that the only way to access user-input is through the `WHERE` -clause. User-input _will_ change, so I can't do an ugly one and hardcode the values.

Comment: The answer to your question is NO, but there might be workarounds. Could call a procedure and send the user input as a parameter? You can contact me via twitter if you want to continue in Swedish.

Comment: Well, I don't know how familiar you are with avaya, but as usual everything is tightly locked down. I have a strong feeling I might break more than just a few "don't modify that or some warranty will break" if I start poking around in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late but nevertheless: there is no standard way to do that. A hacky way would be to save the report you need to a file, edit it and load back into CMS Supervisor. This way you can use almost any kind of query supported by Informix server in CMS.

A slightly easier and still-within-warranty way would be to dump the data you need directly from Informix, load it in Excel or whatever and process there. See my article on how to access Informix data: http://avaya.dwalin.ru/call-management-system/tutorial-using-informix-tools-to-access-cms-historical-database/

Comment: Dumping data isn't an options since it's the real-time data I need. I've tried modifying one of the reports by saving it, but (probably) since it's in some weird format cms throws an error in my face whenever I try to load the report.

Comment: You didn't say you were after real time data; it's a lot trickier to get but it's possible. I see two ways: a) use standard data extraction solution like RT_Socket, put the data in intermediary database and query it there; b) use a custom data dumper to get the data. Standard way is under warranty but is complicated; custom way is easier and cheaper but requires very specific domain knowledge. As for modifying reports, I'm not 100% sure it will work as I only did report dumping and never tried to load them back. I can give you some clues on report format if you're interested.

Comment: RT_Socket is an expensive solution (as always with avaya) and not really an option. Could you define "custom data dumper"?

Comment: There is a standard, albeit undecomented, way to get at real time data: /cms/toolsbin/clint. In essence, that's a command line version of telnet based reports. You can create a custom report to query the data you need and run this report with clint to get the data, which you will have to parse and process: [link](http://tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=397058). In fact, RT_Socket works this way too, as does Generic RTA and other real time data dumpers available from Avaya PSO. To use clint you need External Application RTU on CMS, which is inexpensive (~$500) and may be already on your CMS.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to do this would be to create a custom database view (the name must begin with c_)that encapsulates the logic you are trying to apply. After the view is working, you must then go into the CMS dictionary and add the view as a custom table and add each column. This is needed because that is the only way the view will be available to Designer.